# Fill in Textboxes with Address Info, when Dropdownlist item is selected .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have read a ton of articles and none of them have been much help for in the context I am trying to do this.

I have a Dropdownlist within an Edit User Modal, for **Companies**. When I select an item from the dropdownlist I want it to populate the **Address**, **City**, and **State** inputs. These values are all stored in the DB.

I can't figure out how to do this following quite a few examples I've found online. I may be looking at the wrong examples. Does anyone have any idea(s) or examples they could direct me to?

Edit User Modal:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="user" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="user-tab">
 <form method="post" class="mt-3"  asp-action="EditUser" asp-controller="Administration">
    <input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.ToString()" />
    <div class="form-group row text-center">
        <label asp-for="Id" class="col-sm-3 text-right col-form-label labelFont"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input disabled asp-for="Id" class="formField inputDisabled" disabledclass="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row text-center">
        <label asp-for="FirstName" class="col-sm-3 text-right col-form-label labelFont"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input asp-for="FirstName" class="formField" />
            <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row text-center">
        <label asp-for="LastName" class="col-sm-3 text-right col-form-label labelFont"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input asp-for="LastName" class="formField" />
            <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row text-center">
        <label asp-for="Title" class="col-sm-3 text-right col-form-label labelFont"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input asp-for="Title" class="formField" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row text-center">
        <label asp-for="Email" class="col-sm-3 text-right col-form-label labelFont"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input asp-for="Email" class="formField" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row text-center">
        <label asp-for="UserName" class="col-sm-3 text-right col-form-label labelFont"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input asp-for="UserName" class="formField" />
            <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    @* -------------COMPANY DROPDOWN ------------------------*@
    <div class="form-group row text-center">
        <label asp-for="CompanyLists" class="col-sm-3 text-right col-form-label labelFont"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyId, new SelectList(Model.CompanyLists.OrderBy(x => x.CompanyName), "CompanyID", "CompanyName"), "-- Select Company --", new { @class = "form-control" })
            <span asp-validation-for="CompanyId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row text-center">
        <label asp-for="Address" class="col-sm-3 text-right col-form-label labelFont"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input asp-for="Address" id="Address" class="formField" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Address" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row text-center">
        <label asp-for="City" class="col-sm-3 text-right col-form-label labelFont"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input asp-for="City" id="City" class="formField" />
            <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row text-center">
        <label asp-for="State" class="col-sm-3 text-right col-form-label labelFont"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input asp-for="State" id="State" class="formField" />
            <span asp-validation-for="State" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary padFloat btnBlue" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" data-save="modal">Update</button>
    <a asp-action="UserMaint" class="btn btn-primary padFloat btnRed" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
 </form>
</div>
```

Edit User Method:

```c#
  [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EditUser(string id)
        {
            //GET USER INFORMATION - EXIT IF USER DOESN'T EXIST
            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"User with Id = {id} cannot be found";
                return View("NotFound");
            }

            //GET COMPANY NAME FROM COMPANY ID
            var companyuser = from c in companyRepository.GetCompanys() select c;
            foreach (var c in companyuser)
            {
                ////Store this information into the company list in the viewmodel
                var companyinfo = new EditUserViewModel.CompanyList
                {
                    CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
                    CompanyID = c.CompanyId
                };

            };

            //USER INFORMATION ---------------------------------------
            var model = new EditUserViewModel
            {
                Id = user.Id,
                Email = user.Email,
                UserName = user.UserName,
                FirstName = user.FirstName,
                LastName = user.LastName,
                Title = user.Title,
                Address = user.Address,
                City = user.City,
                State = user.State,
                CompanyId = user.CompanyId
            };


            //COMPANY DROPDOWN INFO------------------------------------
            var company = from c in companyRepository.GetCompanys() select c;
            foreach (var c in company)
            {
                ////Store this information into the company list in the viewmodel
                var companyinfo = new EditUserViewModel.CompanyList
                {
                    CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
                    CompanyID = c.CompanyId,
                };

                model.CompanyLists.Add(companyinfo);
            };         

            //GET LIST OF ROLES(RoleID, RoleName)
            var roles = roleManager.Roles;

            foreach (var RoleName in roles)
            {
                //Execute identity method to get full information for the Role and store into an object (roleinfo)
                var roleString = RoleName.Name;
                var fullRoleInfo = await roleManager.FindByNameAsync(roleString);
                //Store this information into the Role list in the viewmodel
                var roleinfo = new EditUserViewModel.Role
                {
                    RoleName = fullRoleInfo.Name,
                    RoleID = fullRoleInfo.Id,
                };

                if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, roleString))
                {
                    roleinfo.IsSelected = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    roleinfo.IsSelected = false;
                }

                model.Roles.Add(roleinfo);
            };

            //**************************************************************************************************************************************************************
            //IDENTITY CLAIM INFORMATION ------------------------------

            var existingUserClaims = await userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

            foreach (Claim claim in ClaimStore.AllClaims)
            {
                var userClaims = new EditUserViewModel.Claim
                {
                    ClaimType = claim.Type
                };


                if (existingUserClaims.Any(c => c.Type == claim.Type && c.Value == "true"))
                {
                    userClaims.IsSelected = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    userClaims.IsSelected = false;
                }

                model.Claims.Add(userClaims);
            }

            return PartialView("~/Views/Modals/_EditUserModalPartial.cshtml", model);
         }
```

Edit User Model:

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PortalDev.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class EditUserViewModel
    {

        public EditUserViewModel()
        {
            Claims = new List<Claim>();
            Roles = new List<Role>();
            CompanyLists = new List<CompanyList>();
        }

        //ROLES ---------------------------------------------
        public class Role
        {
            public string RoleName { get; set; }
            public string RoleID { get; set; }
            public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

        }
        public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }

        //CLAIMS----------------------------------------------
        public class Claim
        {
            public string ClaimType { get; set; }
            public string ClaimID { get; set; }
            public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
        }
        public List<Claim> Claims { get; set; }

        //COMPANY DROPDOWN--------------------------------------
        public class CompanyList
        {
            public string CompanyName { get; set; }
            public int? CompanyID { get; set; }
            public string PhysicalAddress { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string State { get; set; }
        }
        [Display(Name = "Company")]
        public List<CompanyList> CompanyLists { get; set; }   //List of Companies for dropdown

        //USER INFORMATION --------------------------------------
        public string Id { get; set; }
        //[Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }

        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
        public Company Company { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A select element cannot work with full objects: just key-value pairs. That's usually an id and name. The name is what's displayed as the option in the select and the id is what's then sent back to the server when something is selected and then posted.

If you want additional information about a company (its address for example), you should have an endpoint that returns that info for a given company id, and them make an AJAX request to that endpoint whenever an option is selected.

For example:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompany(int id)
{
    var company = await _context.Companies.FindAsync(id);
    if (company == null) return NotFound();
    return Ok(company);
}
```

Then, you'd have some JS on the page like:

```
document.getElementById('company').addEventListener('change', async () => {
    let companyId = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;
    let company = fetch('/my/endpoint/' + companyId).then(response => response.json());

    // fill in fields
    document.getElementById('companyStreet').value = company.Street;
    // etc.
});
```

*Note: `fetch` is not support in some older browsers (IE). If you need to support those, you should use a polyfill or fallback to using `XMLHttpRequest` (or something like `$.ajax` if using a library like jQuery).*

Comment: is ```_context``` just a private object? I have not used it in this controller yet. (i am still wet behind the ears)

Comment: Yeah. It would be the `DbContext` instance or whatever else you're using to query your database. Just an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `company` info when you choose the selectlist,here is a simple demo like below:

1.Model:

```
public class Company
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string PhysicalAddress { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

2.Edit View:

```
@model EditUserViewModel
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Address" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Address" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Address" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="City" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            //...
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyId, new SelectList(Model.CompanyLists.OrderBy(x => x.CompanyName), "CompanyID", "CompanyName"), "-- Select Company --", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "dropdownlist" })
                <span asp-validation-for="CompanyId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="info"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    <script>
$("#dropdownlist").change(function () {
    var select = $("#dropdownlist").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "/YourController/GetInfo?select=" + select,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#info").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
}
```

3.Partial View:

```
 @model EditUserViewModel
<div class="form-group row text-center">
    <label asp-for="Address" class="col-sm-3 text-right col-form-label labelFont"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input asp-for="Address" id="Address" class="formField" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Address" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row text-center">
    <label asp-for="City" class="col-sm-3 text-right col-form-label labelFont"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input asp-for="City" id="City" class="formField" />
        <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row text-center">
    <label asp-for="State" class="col-sm-3 text-right col-form-label labelFont"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input asp-for="State" id="State" class="formField" />
        <span asp-validation-for="State" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

4.Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    var model = new EditUserViewModel
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        FirstName = user.FirstName,
        LastName = user.LastName,
        Title = user.Title,
        Address = user.Address,
        City = user.City,
        State = user.State,
        CompanyId = user.CompanyId
    };
    var company = from c in companyRepository.GetCompanys() select c;
    foreach (var c in company)
    {
        ////Store this information into the company list in the viewmodel
        var companyinfo = new EditUserViewModel.CompanyList
        {
            CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
            CompanyID = c.CompanyID,
        };

        model.CompanyLists.Add(companyinfo);
    };
    return View(model);
}
public PartialViewResult GetInfo(int select)
{
    var data = _context.Companies.Where(c => c.CompanyID == select).FirstOrDefault();
    var model = new EditUserViewModel()
    {
        Address = data.PhysicalAddress,
        State = data.State,
        City = data.City
    };
    return PartialView("_PartialInfo", model);
}
```

Comment: This makes sense! But, using your example, my view and partial view are the same file :( I am using modals and that's where I am trying to implement this. (EditUser Modal)

Comment: You mean you want to show View and partial view on Modal?

Comment: In my original post, the **Edit User Modal** is a partial view. It already has city state and address in that view. I couldn't get the partial view that you recommended to show up within that partial view. I'd like to just have them autofill when I select from the dropdown and not have to populate a separate partial view for the address to be visible.